# this.props gives undefined while using redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am new to redux. I've passed a value through `mapStateToProps` and `this.props` has value inside `render()`. However, if I console `this.props` in function like in `renderRow` function in the following example, it gives undefined. Why is this the case?

```
constructor() {
    super();
}

renderRow(rowData) {
    //this.console gives undefined why
    console.log('props1', this.props);
}

render() {
    //this.props has value here
    {console.log('props1', this.props)}
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <ListView
            dataSource={this.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />

      </View>
    ); 
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {selectionsList: state.selections, 
            selectionId: state.selectionId};
}
```

Comment: bind your renderRow method like this. {this.renderRow.bind(this)}

Comment: Either `bind` `renderRow` function in constructor or convert it into `arrow` function like `renderRow = (rowData) => {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is that you pass a function to another component, and this function has no binding to your class instance anymore. It has it only if you call it (not pass) with actual object on the left – you can read more in [my article about this](https://blog.bloomca.me/2018/08/24/javascript-fundamentals-this.html). You have several solutions here, and you can read about them in [docs about event handling](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). It is a common pattern when adding an event handler.

So, you can do the following:

1. use class properties:

   renderRow = (rowData) => {
       console.log('props1', this.props);
   }

If you use it this way, it will automatically bind your function to your instance.

2. just create a new arrow function when you pass the callback:

   ```
   <ListView
       dataSource={this.dataSource}
       renderRow={(data) => this.renderRow(data)}
   />
   ```

Arrow functions don't have their own `this`, so it will work correctly.

3. You can bind your method when you pass it as a property. It works almost the same way as the previous one – every time we render, we create a new function:

   ```
   <ListView
       dataSource={this.dataSource}
       renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
   />
   ```
4. Bind in constructor. You can just bind it in constructor – it will create a new function when instantiating, so you won't do it every re-render. It works sort of similar to the first one, but is more explicit (and much more verbose):

   ```
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
   }

   _renderRow(data) {
      console.log('props1', this.props);
   }
   ```

I personally would say just use the first approach, it is very common and stable enough (it is stage 3 in proposals).